# The size of tensor a (42) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, pytorch

The error is coming at line  `correct += (predicted == labels).sum()` of the code below:

```
class CPillModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(CPillModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim) 
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.tanh2 = nn.Tanh()
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.elu3 = nn.ELU()
        
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.elu4 = nn.ELU()
        
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.elu5 = nn.ELU()
        
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.elu6 = nn.ELU()
        
        self.fc7 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)  
        #self.act7 = Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.tanh2(x)
        
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.elu3(x)
        
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.elu4(x)
        
        x = self.fc5(x)
        x = self.elu5(x)
        
        x = self.fc6(x)
        x = self.elu6(x)
        
        x = self.fc7(x)
        #x = self.act7(x)

        return x


input_dim = 9
hidden_dim = 100
output_dim = 10

# Create ANN
model = CPillModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim)

# Cross Entropy Loss 
error = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
#error = nn.MSELoss()

# SGD Optimizer
learning_rate = 0.02
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

count = 0
loss_list = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list = []      
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
# enumerate mini batches
    for i, (data_a, data_b) in enumerate(train_loader):
        train = Variable(data_a)
        labels = Variable(data_b)
        # clear the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # compute the model output
        outputs = model(data_a)
        # calculate loss
        loss = error(outputs, data_b)
        # credit assignment
        loss.backward()
        # update model weights
        optimizer.step()
        count += 1

        if count % 50 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Predict test dataset
            for data_a, data_b in test_loader:

                test = Variable(data_a)
                
                # Forward propagation
                outputs = model(test)
                
                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)[1]
                
                # Total number of labels
                total += len(labels)
                

                # Total correct predictions
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
            
            accuracy = 100 * correct / float(total)
            
            # store loss and iteration
            loss_list.append(loss.data)
            iteration_list.append(count)
            accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
            if count % 500 == 0:
                # Print Loss
                print('Iteration: {}  Loss: {}  Accuracy: {} %'.format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

Do I need to change the predicted variable.

Comment: The print of predicted and labels shape are: 100 and 42 respectively. So they are not equal. The error is from the '==' operator.

Comment: What is the shape of `outputs.data`? I'm not familiar with pytorch but on tensorflow you can call `tensor.shape` to get the full shape of a tensor. Something like `(1, 100, 100, 3)` if you have a single 3 channel image.

Comment: Please provide the shapes for `outputs` and `labels`. As well as the full error stack trace.

Comment: The shape of output is [42,10] and the shape of the labels is [100]. The full-stack error trace is:                                                                                                                                 
     43 
     44                 # Total correct predictions
---> 45                 correct += (predicted == labels).sum()

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (42) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 0

Comment: This worked: correct += (predicted[i] == labels[i]).sum() but my accuracy are very low.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your model ? And please put the (full) stack trace in your question, not in the comments

Comment: I have now added the code for the model. Thanks